# Print random elements from an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to print array elements randomly using jquery functions. I've generated the random number count using math.random but unable to print array elements in the html document.
(.print-que) is a class in html which i'm referencing here.
Also there is an identifier expected error while accesing the array elements using jquery object. any solutions for this?

```
function kidzee() {

    var que = [
        "Click on a circle shaped object",
        "Click on a rectangle shaped object",
        "Click on a triangle shaped object",
        "Click on a square shaped object",
        
    ];
    

    var queArr = que.length;

    

    function generateQuestion() {
        //var len = que.length;
        //Generates random question and displays it
        var queNo = Math.floor((Math.random() * queArr-1) + 0);
        $(".print-que").html( que.[queNo] );
        
    }




    return {
        generateQuestion : generateQuestion
    }
}

var kidzeeInstance = kidzee();
kidzeeInstance.generateQuestion();
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to first of all _show us_ what you actually tried. And a bit more context, what _exactly_ you want here, would probably not do any harm either.

Comment: I actually forgot to add the code earlier now I've edited the post with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check **que.[queNo]** and replace it with **que[queNo]**

```
$(".print-que").html( que[queNo] );
```

```js
function kidzee() {
    var que = [
        "Click on a circle shaped object",
        "Click on a rectangle shaped object",
        "Click on a triangle shaped object",
        "Click on a square shaped object"            
    ];       

    var queArr = que.length;       

    function generateQuestion() {
        //var len = que.length;
        //Generates random question and displays it           
        var queNo = Math.floor((Math.random() * queArr-1) + 0);          
        $(".print-que").html( que[queNo] );
        
    }
    return {
        generateQuestion : generateQuestion
    }
}

var kidzeeInstance = kidzee();
kidzeeInstance.generateQuestion();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="print-que">

</div>
```

Comment: Also I had to add document.ready() to the js file to load the script after html elements & it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It does not need jquery. Just use 'Math. Random' to get the index you want using javascript.it returns a random number between 0 (inclusive),  and 1 (exclusive).
Then you can multiple the value with array length and to have integer value, you can use math.floor or round.

```
var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
```

You can use this value to access the array randomly. Replace the length variable  with the size of array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this once -
$(".print-que").append(Math.floor(Math.random() * que.length));

Comment: It actually prints the random array index not the value associated with the index .              `var queNo = Math.floor((Math.random() * queArr-1) + 0);          
        $(".print-que").html( que[queNo] );`  This worked perfectly